# $A^n$ formula not working; checked arithmetic

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I'm trying to find the general formula for a matrix raised to a certain power using diagonalization.
My original matrix $A$ is:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  -3 & 2 \\
 -12 & 7
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
My eigenvector matrix $P$ is:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 1/2 & 1/3 \\
 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
I found the diagonal matrix $D$ to be:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & 3
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
And $P^{-1}$ is:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  6 & -2 \\
 -6 &  3
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The final formula I got from multiplying $P D^n P^{-1}$ is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  3- 6^n & -1+3^n \\
  6-18^n & -2+9^n
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
It checks out in the case of $A^1$ but not $A^0$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: \bmatrix gives square brackets, \pmatrix gives parentheses

Comment: @DaniJo: Your eigenvalues / eigenvectors are correct. However, check your multiplication, for example $-2 \times 3^n \ne -6^n$.

Comment: $P, P^{-1},D$ are all fine. The problem is in the last bit.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations for $PD^nP^{-1}$ are wrong. Check them.

Remember that, for instance, $2\cdot 3^n \neq 6^n$.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the computation by choosing the matrix
$$
P=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}
$$
so that
$$
P^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & -1 \\ -2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Therefore, with more accurate computations,
\begin{align}
P\begin{bmatrix} 1^n & 0 \\ 0 & 3^n \end{bmatrix}P^{-1}
&=P\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 3^n \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix} 3 & -1 \\ -2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\\[6px]
&=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 3 \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix} 3 &-1  \\ -2\cdot3^n & 3^n \end{bmatrix}
\\[6px]
&=\begin{bmatrix} 3-2\cdot3^n & 3^n-1 \\ 6(1-3^{n}) & 3^{n+1}-2 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}